# Getting an element inside ng-init and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-init to do some initialization when a particular element loads. In my template, I'm doing this:

```
<div id="timer-0" ng-init="initTimer('timer-0', timerOne);"></div>
```

timerOne is an object declared in the controller's scope, which looks something like this:

```
$scope.timerOne = {...};

$scope.initTimer = function(id, timer)
{
  var element = angular.element("#"+id);
  // a bunch of other stuff with the timer and element interacting with each other
}
```

Everything works fine when my HTML is hard-coded like that, but when I start trying to call initTimer inside an ng-repeat, angular.element is returning nothing.

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="timer in timers">
  <h1>{{timer.label}}</h1>
  <div id="timer-{{$index}}" ng-init="initTimer('timer-'+$index, timer);"></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that the elements are getting inserted into the DOM after ng-init is called. Is there any way to call my init function once I know for sure these elements exist?

Comment: Why do you need id at all? btw id should be `id="timer-{{$index}}"`

Comment: First, don't use `ng-init` to initialize - initialize in the controller. Second, don't refer to DOM (with `angular.element("#"+id)`) in the controller.

Comment: @NewDev That is a great point, i see lot of ng-init abuse as well in many questions.. :) Nobody reads the [first line in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: if i can answer for the sake of answering, i would write wrap DOM access  in $timeout so that it will be pushed to async event queue and will run after the current digest cycle. But ideally you shouldn't worry about DOM while using bindings.

Comment: Use a directive, that is what they are meant for. You have direct element access and no need for ID

Answer (score 1):

Just pass index as parameter in the init function.

```
<div ng-repeat="timer in timers">
  <h1>{{timer.label}}</h1>
  <div id="{{'timer-'+$index}}" ng-init="initTimer($index, timer);"></div>
</div>
```

And In controller try to access the element like this:

```
$scope.initTimer = function(id, timer)
{
    var element = angular.element('timer-' + id);
}
```